# How can I write $\prod\limits_{i = 0}^n {\left( {x - {x_i}} \right)} $ in terms of a polynomial as $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{a_i}{x^n}} $?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-linear-algebra

How can I write $\prod\limits_{i = 0}^n {\left( {x - {x_i}} \right)} $ in terms of a polynomial as $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{a_i}{x^n}} $? In the other words, is there a way to write $a_i$ in terms of $x_i$?

Comment: You can using [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) and [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: the $a_i$'s are Vieta's formulas since the $x_i$'s are the roots of the polynomial and the coefficient of $x^n$ is 1.